# Email sending program approach in C#?

Tags: c#, email

Imagine you're creating an email sending program using c# that send a "Welcome" email and a "Come back" email to your customers. The idea is that the application runs every day as a scheduled job. When the run it is printed if it went well or badly. How would you approach this? How would you think the architecture would look? And would you use any special techniques?

Comment: Hi, you could use [Task Scheduler](https://github.com/dahall/taskscheduler) to schedule the task and any database to store information about the mail outs. There are many services that provide this sort of marketing automation like Marketo or HubSpot.

Comment: `if it went well or badly.` What constitutes 'well' or 'badly'?

Comment: Major ESPs (like my employer - click my name to see who they are (I won't put it here to avoid appearance as spam), and there are many competitors) will have functionality to do this reasonably easily. They'll have some kind of notion of 'here is a list, send an email to someone when they join the list' etc etc. Then you will programmatically add an email address to the list, and they'll take care of the rest. Also, now the email can be setup / edited by marketing without developers needing to be involved.

Answer (score 0):

Use the MailMessage class to send emails.

Check it out here below:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.mail.mailmessage?view=netframework-4.8

You can use either a console or a windows forms project for this. Keep the app open and use the DateTime class to loop through each day.

More about the DateTime class here:
https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/learn-about-datetime-in-c-sharp/

You can then use an MS SQL database to serve as your log for this application.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure of you have heard about Hangfire, but I found it quite useful and easy to use to setup recurrent tasks like the one you described.

https://www.hangfire.io/